# What does void mean?

Tags: java, c++, c, void

I see void a lot often in Java, C++ and C Programming Languages.
I am actually Electrical Guy that is aspiring to be a Developer.

Comment: void means nothing or having no type

Comment: you answered you own question in your question. Void means that a method does not return anything to the caller

Comment: `void` means nothing or in another sense everything. :)

Comment: @Patrick careful with the capitalization - whilst this question is asking about multiple languages, in Java `Void` and `void` mean different things. A method whose return type is `Void` must return a `java.lang.Void` reference (i.e. there must be an explicit `return` statement).

Comment: Step 1 is to choose the language you want to study. Step 2 is to read a book. Here's a [list of books](http://stackoverflow.com/a/562377/3386109) about the C language.

Comment: "I am actually Electrical Guy that is aspiring to be a Developer" good for you, the world needs people with that skillset. But I'm pretty sure you didn't learn electrical engineering by pointing at a component on a print board and ask "what does that do?"

Answer (score 9):

It means "no type". It is used as function argument, generic data pointer and function return value. For example, if your function return value is void (the one before the name of the function) like `void ex_func (void)` it means it doesn't return anything. Or if it's `int ex_func (void)` it takes no argument. Lastly, `void * ex_data` is a pointer to a data that is unspecified or unknown and therefore it can't be dereferenced. Dereferencing means getting the value that is stored in the memory pointed by the pointer.

[More information on void type in case you're interested.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_type)